# Can't access kivy.garden.matplotlib

Tags: kivy

Everything in installed and has the latest version but when I'm trying to import *FigureCanvasKivyAgg* :

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
```

it says under *matplotlib* that: "Cannot find reference 'matplotlib' in '**init**.py'"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of matplotlib you are using ??

Comment: version 3.4.3, why?

Comment: Try downgrading matplotlib to version 2.1.1, kivy garden.matplotlib is using an older version of matplotlib and hasn't got any updates

Comment: I tried several versions but each time it says: "ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib==2.0.0". even though the right version is shown among the available ones!